# output function result in powershell write-host

Tags: function, powershell, active-directory

i'm attempting to write the result of the 
`$x = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($name)` statement into my write-host string but am encounter some issues with getting the result from the function into the output.

here's the relevant code:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

function fu($name)
{
 $x = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($name).value
if ($x -ne $null){
    Write-Host{ $x } 
}
else{
    Write-Host{"Null"} 
}
}

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=CorpServers,DC=corp,DC=com,DC=net' -Server      "corp.com.net" -Filter * -Properties * |ForEach-Object{write-host "add filter filterlist=""L2-Windows Servers"" srcaddr=any dstaddr=$(fu $_.Name) description=""$($_.Name)"""}
```

currently it just outputs the string as is, but when it reaches the fu subexpression seems to not properly perform the logic and only outputs "$x" literally, where my intent was to have it output the IP of the current obj in the foreach-object statement.

Comment: `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(<<hostname>>) | Get-Member` does not show any `value` property ? You may simply try running this - `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(<<hostname>>)` first in your ISE / console.

Comment: Did you intend something like this instead - [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("<<hostname>>")[0].ToString() in `function fu()` ?

Comment: Alter $x to something like: `$x = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($name)|select-object IPAddressToString -expandproperty  IPAddressToString` ?

Comment: Yea, but it will return multiple values. Right ?

Comment: well i wanted to call the fu function from within the foreach-object cmd and supply it with a the current objs $_.Name, so i thought it would return a single IP address connected with the obj specified by its $_.Name?

Comment: If i insert `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($_.Name)` inline within the Get-ADComputer cmdlet inplace of the $(fu $_.Name) it gives me the desired result, but i cannot apply the "if address is null then..." logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you put `$x` in curly brackets `{}`.

Just do `Write-Host $x`

Comment: Wow... I've been in to many meetings today lol, Thanks SpellingD

Answer (score 1):

I expand a bit the code for the explanation but try this :

```
function fu($name)
{
  $res = $null
  $x = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($name)
  if ($x -ne $null)
  {
     $res = $x
  }
  return $res
}

$a = fu "localhost"
$a
$a.gettype().fullname
```

It does what you want, $a is an array of data. But you have to understand that the following functions gives different results

```
function fu($name)
{
  $res = $null
  $x = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($name)
  if ($x -ne $null)
  {
     $res = $x
  }
  Write-Host $res
}

Clear-Host
$a = fu "localhost"
$a
$a | Get-Member
```

The las one give again the good result. `return` and `write-out` both write data in the output of the function. `Write-host` just write to the host.

```
function fu($name)
{
  $res = $null
  $x = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($name)
  if ($x -ne $null)
  {
     $res = $x
  }
  Write-output $res
}

Clear-Host
$a = fu "localhost"
$a
$a | Get-Member
```

Answer (score 0):

`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(<<hostname>>) | Get-Member` does not show any **value** property ?

You may try [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/44e9fef7-a04b-40b3-bb05-97659e56e27e) function instead.